# How can I use Mnist dataset in MapReduce project?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mnist, rbm

I am new to MapReduce. I learnt about MapReduce through wordcount problem in which  pair was easily understandable. But now I have Mnist data-set (normalized images) to train the Restricted Boltzmann Machine. I don't know how to use that data-set. How can I obtain  pairs from the data-set and specially what will be the type of keys and values?